# How to remove duplicate imported photos in Shotwell

Tags: shotwell, photo-management, tag, duplicate

I've noticed that Shotwell has imported many images twice (e.g. from my camera SD card). Apparently the [duplicate detection is buggy](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=719253) once a photo is imported, tagged and then re-imported.

I have "write meta data tags" enabled in the settings. If I import a photo `test-images.jpg` and add tags to it the photo will *not* be picked up by the duplicate detection upon another import of the same file.
The second time the file is imported it will be named `test-images-1.jpg` and placed in the library folder as per the active rules (not necessarily into the same folder).

`test-images.jpg` and `test-images-1.jpg` will have the same image data but due to the added tag/metadata the files are not the same anymore and won't be picked up by searching for duplicates (e.g. md5 hash).

My usage scenario that caused multiple duplicate is as follows:

1. I take pictures with my phone
2. I import the photos from my phone, add tags but leave the images on the phone as I want to keep them for sharing etc.
3. I add further tags to the imported photos
4. After some weeks I repeat the import step from the phone and old photos that I have already imported will be imported again (with '-1.jpg' or '-2.jpg' added)

**How to clean up the duplicates?**
Using a file name based search would be possible but I can't exclude that I have not imported a file ending with `-1` to which was not imported as a duplicate.

How can I clean up my photo library? I tried to use the search function in Shotwell but with more than 1000 photos there must be a better, more reliable, less error prone an simpler way.

I'm not to worried about tags getting lost, typically the second import (the duplicate) has no tags applied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use fdupes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177346/how-to-use-fdupes)

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. As described in the linked bug Shotwell has detection for duplicates but once the first imported file was tagged (and the tag written to the file) the fingerprint/hash of the file changes. Thus the first imported file is different from the next imported file although they might be the same file (when imported).

Comment: If the files differ in their hash, and you do not see some sort of pattern to the duplicate files, you would have to manually resolve the problem. Can you update your question with the information you posted in your comment and post additional information on the files.

Answer (score 4):

Sort of spamish, but I found myself with the same problem a few monts ago, and I wrote a small utility that does just that:

https://github.com/jesjimher/imgdupes

It's a python script that scans a directory tree looking for duplicates. Its syntax is intentionally similar to fdupes, with the difference that imgdupes ignores all metadata and analyzes only the image data chunk of a JPEG file. This means that two different versions of the same image, with different tags, rotation flags, dates, etc., will be reported as duplicates even if physical files are different (and thus not detected as duplicates by fdupes/shotwell).

It was recently renamed to jpegdupes, and is now on Pypi repos, so scanning a tree for duplicated images might be done like this:

`sudo pip install jpegdupes
jpegdupes -d ~/Photos/` (or whatever your path is)

It would look for JPEGs which are actually the same picture (differing only in metadata), and would interactively show differences and ask for which version to keep.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, I will give this a shot... besides the other options I have tried. e.g. the search suggestion

Comment: This is a great tool, just what I needed. It should be integrated into Shotwell.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem a few weeks ago. The solution I found to resolve this issue is basic but works : inside Shotwell, make a new saved search that displays all pictures not tagged AND with filenames ending with "_1.jpg".
You can then erase all files listed by Shotwell for this search but be careful, make a backup before ;-)
In my case I deleted 2000+ pictures !

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy the tagged files back to your phone, so they aren't different any more? I think Shotwell ought to cope with it's own tagging though, and this does look like a bug to me.
I have a similar problem, but with Shotwell re-developing camera raw files every time it's run.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and solved by exporting all images from Shotwell into another folder. Even if you have dups, Shotwell shows them only once. For instance I had 64K in the folder but Shotwell showed only 32K. So I selected all and exported preserving size, name, metadata etc. 
The only downside is: if you had complicated folder structure and you want to keep it - this solution may not work for you. I have everything in one folder now. BTW looks like this bug is fixed now.