# How can I stop Shotwell creating duplicate files?

Tags: shotwell

I'm using Shotwell to re-group my large photo collection; version 0.20.2.
There are a number of Canon .crw files.
If I use the 'camera' developer, every time I rum shotwell it creates hundreds of *embedded.jpg files. Or embedded_1.jpg.. _2.jpg.....
If I use the 'Shotwell' developer the same happens but with shotwell_n.jpg files.

How can I prevent this misbehaviour & is it a known bug (not found here or Googling)?

Answer (score 2):

I see the [same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489951/how-to-remove-duplicate-imported-photos-in-shotwell?rq=1) has been asked, and there is indeed a known bug - so it's not just me!

Comment: can you mention the bug ?

Comment: This is it in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=719253) - it was referenced in the same question.