# How to delete duplicated files based on pattern (see examples below) using a script or a Bash command

Tags: bash, scripts, video

My question is simple :

I have video files named as follows :

- `xxxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4`
- `xxxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4`

where yyy can vary in length (e.g yyyyyy or more y)

As I'm not used in shell scripts I'd like to delete automatically (in a specified folder)

- If a file with the name `xxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4` exists and **if** the file `xxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4` exists, delete `xxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4`
- If there is only a file `xxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4` and **not** a file `xxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4`, do nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use fdups http://askubuntu.com/questions/177346/how-to-use-fdupes

Comment: Is it only in `xxxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4` the the number of `y` may vary or is it also in `xxxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4`? If so, how do those things relate (i.e. should any file matching `xxxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4` be deleted regardless of the number of `y` in `xxxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4`)?

Comment: the number of yyy can vary from one set of files to another but i'd like to delete files files with the same yyy number and if the couple of files  xxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4 and  xxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4 exist the xxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4 has to be deleted

Comment: Contrary to the proposition of using fdupes, fslint or DupeGuru my question is to complicated to use those tools

Comment: As I mentioned the number of yyy can vary but I want to delete xxx_yyyy_720_8000.mp4 only if the file xxx_yyyy_720_3800.mp4 exists with the strictly same yyyy pattern.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `find` and `gawk`

1. Install `gawk`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gawk
   ```
2. Go into your folder or replace the `.` after the `find` command with your foldername, eg: `find ~/my_video_duplicates f -iname …`
3. Test the command

   The command below shows only the remove candidates

   ```
   find . -type f -iname "*_8000.mp4" -print0 | \
       while read -d $'\0' file; do \
           gawk -F_ '{ \
               a=gensub(/\_8000\./, "_3800.", "g" , $0); \
               system("if [ -f \""a"\" ]; then echo \""a"\" will be deleted; fi")}' <<< "$file";\
       done
   ```
4. Check again, if you are in the right folder or replace the `.` after the `find` command with your foldername, eg: `find ~/my_video_duplicates f -iname …`
5. If you sure, run the command below

   ```
   find . -type f -iname "*_8000.mp4" -print0 | \
       while read -d $'\0' file; do \
           gawk -F_ '{ \
               a=gensub(/\_8000\./, "_3800.", "g" , $0); \
               system("if [ -f \""a"\" ]; then rm \""a"\"; fi")}' <<< "$file";\
       done
   ```

---

*Example*

- The starting situation

  ```
  % ls -og
  total 3
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Jul 14 19:37 xxxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Jul 14 19:20 xxxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Jul 14 19:21 aaaa_yyy_720_8000.mp4
  ```
- The dry run

  ```
  % find . -type f -iname "*_8000.mp4" -print0 | \
      while read -d $'\0' file; do \
          gawk -F_ '{ \
              a=gensub(/\_8000\./, "_3800.", "g" , $0); \
              system("if [ -f \""a"\" ]; then echo \""a"\" will be deleted; fi")}' <<< "$file";\
      done
  ./xxxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4 will be deleted
  ```
- The removal

  ```
  % find . -type f -iname "*_8000.mp4" -print0 | \
      while read -d $'\0' file; do \
          gawk -F_ '{ \
              a=gensub(/\_8000\./, "_3800.", "g" , $0); \
              system("if [ -f \""a"\" ]; then rm \""a"\"; fi")}' <<< "$file";\
      done
  ```
- The final situation

  ```
  % ls -og
  total 2
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Jul 14 19:20 xxxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Jul 14 19:21 aaaa_yyy_720_8000.mp4
  ```

Comment: Thank you A.B. but I tried the first of your commands (the one to echo the name of the file to be deleted) in a test folder containing a couple of  xxxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4 and a xxxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4 files but it echoes nothing. As I'm not a gawk specialist I'm not able to tell what's wrong

Comment: Nothing or an error message? Can you post an example of the filenames? In my script, I check only the 8000 part

Comment: Nothing is displayed (the file $0 will be deleted is not displayed). No error message. example of a couple of files xxx_yyyy_720_3800.mp4 and  xxx_yyyy_720_8000.mp4 in the same test folder. if the yyyy vary from one file to another then the files must NOT be considered as "duplicates"

Comment: @Laurent06000 If your file name ends with`*_8000.mp4` as described in your question, then something is displayed.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake but here what I get in a terminal on a testing folder : find . -type f -iname "*_8000.mp4" -print0 | \
>     while read -d $'\0' file; do \
>         gawk -F_ '{ \
>             a=gensub(/\_8000\./, "_3800.", "g" , $0); \
>             system("if [ -f \""a"\" ]; then echo \""a"\" will be deleted; fi")}' <<< "$file";\
>     done
./xxx_yyyy_720p_3800.mp4 will be deleted
laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~/Vidéos$ ./xxxx_yyyy_720_3800.mp4 will be deleted with yyyy stricly the same. I'll try it live on my real forler. Many thanks. Laurent

Answer (score 1):

### Using the `Bash` Shell

`[ -f "file" ]` checks whether a filename exists, and is an ordinary file (e.g. not a directory or symbolic link)

`"${name/%x/y}"` replaces the suffix `x` of `$name` with `y`.

Therefore to delete `xxx_yyy_720_3800.mp4` only if `xxx_yyy_720_8000.mp4` exists, where `xxx` and `yyy` are identical in each case, `for` all `*_*_720_3800.mp4` `in` the current directory:

```
for name in *_*_720_3800.mp4
do if [ -f "${name/%3800.mp4/8000.mp4}" ]
   then echo "$name"
   fi
done
```

Change the `echo` to `rm` if you are sure this is OK.

Comment: Thank you Martin, but this solution does not appear to be a safe one : keep in mind that only files with yyyy be the same between  xxx_yyyy_720_3800.mp4 and  xxx_yyyy_720_8000.mp4 files can be considered as "duplicates".

Comment: It is correct.  `foo_bar_720_3800.mp4` would only be deleted  if exactly `foo_bar_720_8000.mp4` exists, and `foo_baz_720_3800.mp4` would only be deleted  if exactly `foo_baz_720_8000.mp4` exists.  Maybe I confused you with: `"${name/%x/y}" replaces the suffix x of $name with y.`  That x=`720_3800.mp4` and that y=`720_8000.mp4`  Each name is considered separately.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake but your script seems to work on a testing folder. I'll try it live in the real folder. Many thanks. Laurent