# fdupes command line help requested

Tags: command-line

I have a large number of files of mixed format spread over eight directories on an external hard drive.

I know I can use [fdupes](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fdupes.1.html) to sort and remove duplicates on the drive.

Is there any way to command [fdupes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177346/how-to-delete-duplicate-files-with-fdupes?rq=1) to search within only specified directories on the drive and omitting the others?

For example:  Eight directories on drive - A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H.

I wish to search for duplicates within directories A, B, E, and F  but exclude C, D, E and H.

Can anyone point me towards the correct syntax to enable this please?

Comment: Try `fdupes CDEH --recurse: ABEF -nfmq` and see if it shows the desired result. If it does, then modify the command line to actually delete instead of list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion. Sadly however, your suggestion did not work, but with a little experimentation, I think I have found the solution.

Using my original example (above) I used the command:

~$ fdupes -ndN /path/to/drive {A,B,E}

I found this deletes duplicates within the specified folders {A.B.E} only, in accordance with the parameters set (-ndN), and ignores the rest of the directories on the drive.

It also works for subdirectories under a parent directory if the path is modified.